# JHipster: merge changes introduced by new versions of JHipster ( upgrade an application that has manual changes to a new version of JHipster)

Tags: git, jhipster

Please I would like to know the best workflow (best practices) to merge changes resulting from the following two scenarios :

- changes introduced by new versions of [JHipster](https://jhipster.github.io/)
- changes introduced by manually editing the code generated by [JHipster](https://jhipster.github.io/)

I am using [JHipster](https://jhipster.github.io/) in an academic setting and use Git as a version control system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both cases, make sure those changes (manual or not) are done in isolation in a branch stating from a commit representing the first generation, *before* any local changes (versioned in subsequent commits).

Then [`git merge`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) that branch to your main branch in order to get a unified version.

If your branch started from a first code generation commit, that means you have a common ancestor between your current modifications and the new modifications introduced by JHipster.

Note: normally, generated code is not versioned, but in the cse of JHipster, it could generate a *template* app, in which case local modifications are to be done to customize the app. Versioning the all result is in that case recommended.